# Leaflet - Feature data does not update in realtime

Tags: jquery, json, leaflet, geojson

Good evening, I have a problem with leaflet-realtime, updating the coordinates, the icon moves on the map, however if the values ​​in the properties on the map change and in the popup they do not change.
Ex.
The rotation of the marker does not change, speed data does not change. etc..

Here is the code I wrote:

```
var map = L.map('map', {minZoom: 3, maxZoom: 18});
L.Control.measureControl().addTo(map);
mapLink = 'Esri';
wholink = 'i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community';
L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
attribution: '© '+mapLink+', '+wholink,
maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(map);

var shipLayer = L.layerGroup();

var realtime = L.realtime(
{
url: 'http://localhost/api/xxx/',
crossOrigin: true,
type: 'json',
},
{
interval: 2 * 1000,
getFeatureId: function(featureData){
return featureData.properties.idRisorsa;
},
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
var track = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'https://localhost' + feature.properties.TipoRisorsa + '.png',
iconSize: [30, 30]
});
tracker = L.marker(latlng, {icon: track, rotationAngle: feature.properties.Angolo, title: feature.properties.NomePilota + " " + feature.properties.MarcaDrone} );
tracker.bindPopup('Id: ' + feature.properties.idRisorsa +
'
Angolo: ' + feature.properties.Angolo +
'
Nome:' + feature.properties.NomePilota +'' +
'
Marca:' + feature.properties.MarcaDrone +
'
Coordinate: ' + latlng);
tracker.addTo(shipLayer);
return tracker;
}}).addTo(map);

realtime.on('update', function() {realtime.getBounds(), {maxZoom: 18};});
map.setView([0, 0], 0);
```

Comment: Your `pointToLayer()` function only gets run once when the realtime layer is first created. After that, the location of each marker is updated by `realtime` but no other properties change - you need to do this in your `update` handler. The `updateEvent` helpfully passes you a hash of which markers have been updated so you can process this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... But I'm not very good, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You must use [updateEvent](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime#updateevent).

updateEvent.features is an object with keys representing the feature IDs and their corresponding feature objects.

There is an example:

```
realtime.on('update', function (updateEvent) {
  for (var featureId in updateEvent.features) {
    var updatedFeature = updateEvent.features[featureId];
    var layer = realtime.getLayer(featureId);

    if (layer) {
      // Update tooltip content
      layer.setTooltipContent(updatedFeature.properties.name);

      // Update popup content
      layer.setPopupContent(`<div class="card text-primary border-warning mb-3" style="max-width: 21rem;">
        <div class="card-header bg-transparent border-warning">
          <h5><img src="${updatedFeature.properties.marker}">: ${updatedFeature.properties.name}</h5>
        </div>
        ...
        </div>
      </div>`);
    }
  }

    map.fitBounds(realtime.getBounds(), { maxZoom: 15 });
});
```